# Is there a way to set the desired range of an imputation algorithm?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, mortality

Goal: I am interested to learn if there is a way to set the range of an imputation algorithm for Missing Not at Random (NMAR) data, such as Multiple Imputation or Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Background:  I am currently analyzing mortality data from CDC WONDER.  The CDC suppresses citizens' health data in a region if there are so few instances that the confidentiality of the subjects and the reliability of the results are jeopardized.  For example, in the CDC's Multiple Cause of Death data, if the number of deaths in a county is less than 10 over the time period indicated, the CDC will specify the number of deaths as 'Suppressed,' in place of the actual value.  Thus, I want to know if there is a way to use an imputation algorithm for NMAR data when the potential outcomes are only [0,9].

I am sure that others have run into similar problems, so any words of advice and links to explanations or R/Python (or similar) tutorials would be appreciated.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update for all those who have the same problem with CDC data:

The [CDC WONDER Suppression Toolkit](http://www.webdmap.com/suppression) fixes the suppression issue, and employs an algorithm described [here](http://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/abs/10.2105/AJPH.2014.301900).

However, the site is *not* compatible with Mac or Linux systems.